# Can't find file templates for Source Signing in Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, code-signing-entitlements

In my Xcode 4.2 project, I've created an Ad Hoc configuration and want to add the code signing entitlements file to the project, which is usually named Entitlements.plist.

In the past, I create this by selecting a folder in the project tree on the left, then context clicking, selecting "New File...". In the dialog that comes up there's usually a "Code Signing" entry in the iOS tree of the left -- but it's missing now.

The items that *are* there are as follows:

> ```
> Cocoa Touch
> C and C++
> User Interface
> Core Data
> Resource 
> Other
> ```

I've googled for a solution, and searched on Stackoverflow, but not turned up an answer.

I know that I could create an empty plist manually, and just put in the usual default data which is findable on the web somewhere, but it's bothering me that I can't find the usual thing.

Comment: Have you something to add in this file? Default Entitlements.plist is no more required in iOS project

Comment: Mathieu, thanks for that, I wasn't sure if Entitlements.plist was a requirement any more or not. Do you have a reference to any info that authoritively says that this plist isn't required any more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I can't find out an actual reference saying that the code signing entitlements template isn't there any more by design, I have found a reference stating entitlements are not needed: https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TROUBLESHOOTING_GUIDE-CODE_SIGNING_ENTITLEMENTS.

So I'm assuming it's by design in newer versions of XCode.

Answer (score -3):

Try removing the Code Signing Entitlements configuration from the project and target build settings and try your build again.
For more details refer https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TROUBLESHOOTING_GUIDE-CODE_SIGNING_ENTITLEMENTS

Comment: The problem isn't that my entitlements are invalid, it is that I can't create an entitlement file in the usual way -- see my question again.